# How to find <a> using selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The page i want to interact with contains:

`<a class="qwe" onclick="abc;">`

I cannot find a way to click that object using selenium.
Tried: 
`By.XPath("/a[contains(text(),'qwe')]"` and 
`By.ClassName("qwe")`

It doesn't find anything.

```
<div class="page-characterselect">
<div class="charselect">
<div><ul><li>
<a class="Player_Controller" onclick="client.characterSelect('XYZ@ABC');">
<h4 class="char-list-name">XYZ</h4>
<h5 class="char-list-level">Level <span>24</span></h5>
<h5 class="char-list-class">Control Wizard</h5>
<h5 class="char-list-race">Sun Elf</h5>
</a>
</li></ul></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`By.XPath("/a[contains(text(),'qwe')]"` is wrong XPath, because it starts from current node and looks for link text equals "qwe", but what you want is class name.

You should have posted your HTML from the beginning. Here are my suggestions.

```
By.XPath(".//div[@class='charselect']//a[@class='Player_Controller']");
By.CssSelector(".charselect .Player_Controller");
```

If there are other links with class `Player_Controller`, then you need post more `<li>` to see what are the differences between those.

Comment: Only one Player_Controller class link so the first one should work. Thank you!

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: The given selector .//div[@class='charselect']//a[@class='Player_Controller')] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:

InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//div[@class='charselect']//a[@class='Player_Controller')] because of the following error:

[Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: "<unknown>"]

Comment: @user2835249: Yes, I made a typo when updating the answer. (I will update the answer, but you should be able to debug and figure it out yourself, ;))